# Solve parametric equations satisfying that the equations have positive roots....

Tags: systems-of-equations, rational-functions, symmetric-functions

Solve parametric equations satisfying that the equations have positive roots:
$\left\{\begin{matrix}
x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+...+x_{m} &=9 \\ 
\frac{1}{x_{1}}+\frac{1}{x_{2}}+\frac{1}{x_{3}}+...+\frac{1}{x_{m}} &=1 
\end{matrix}\right.$

---

At this problem, I know that $m$ should be $2$.
However, how can I point out that $m=2$ is the only solutions while I do not know to prove the equations have no positive roots when $m>2$?

Please help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, how do you know m = 2 works?

Comment: Btw m = 3 works. All 3 numbers as $3$.

Comment: @Math Lover By my experience, the amouts of equations that are equal or more than $m$ , then they always can be solved

Comment: It is not necessary that the values obtained will be positive roots. Anyway in this case, if you take $m=2$, $x+y = 9$ and also $xy = 9$ based on the give equations. Also, as I said $x = y = z = 3$ is a solution for $m=3$ (just an example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on AM HM inequality -

$\frac{x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+...+x_{m}}{m} \ge \frac{m}{ 
\frac{1}{x_{1}}+\frac{1}{x_{2}}+\frac{1}{x_{3}}+...+\frac{1}{x_{m}}}$

$x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+...+x_{m} \ge m^2 \,$ as ${\frac{1}{x_{1}}+\frac{1}{x_{2}}+\frac{1}{x_{3}}+...+\frac{1}{x_{m}}} = 1$

As $x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+...+x_{m} = 9$, max value of $m$ can be $3$ and as there is equality for $m = 3$, you can find that $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = 3$ is a solution.